# Constructors in Swift

Tags: swift, class, object, constructor

I need some help in constructors in swift. I am sorry, if this question is incorrect or repeated, but I didn't found an answer to my question in another links. So, I have a class

```
class myClass {
  override init(){
    print("Hello World")
  }
}
```

And I have an another class

```
class anotherClass {
 let variable = myClass()
 }
```

Could somebody correct this code? Because it gives me error. I don't know how to explain my question in Swift, because I am newbie. But I will try to explain it, I want to say that when I create an object of the class "myClass", firstly constructor should work and print "Hello World". Thank you!

Comment: It's fairly unhelpful to say that you're getting an error, then not say what the error is.

Comment: Get rid of `override`.  You aren't overriding anything.  Class names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Remove the `override` keyword in the first class. Unlike in ObjC when all classes ultimately inherit from `NSObject`, Swift classes can have no superclass at all. You were not overriding anything

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your init method shouldn't have `override` keyword as it's not a subclass :

```
class myClass {
  init(){
    print("Hello World")
  }
}
```

And if your class is a subcass, you have to call `super.init()` in your `init()` method

Answer (score 0):

In myClass, there is no meaning of `override` before the **init** keyword because it's a Parent class itself and it does not inherited to any other class.So you habe to simply write:

```js
class myClass {
  init(){
    print("Parent Class")
  }
}
```

subClass should be like:

```js
class anotherClass {
 let sub=myClass()
}
```

Now if an instance of anotherClass is created ,it will call the create an instance of myClass inside the subClass and call the `init()` method of myClass and print "Hello World"

> Note:

If anotherClass will be the child class of myClass then:
subClass should be like:

```js
class anotherClass {
 override init(){
    print("Child Class")
  }
}
```

Now if an instance of subClass is created ,it will call the subClass constructor first then the parent class constructor

```js
var sub=anotherClass()
//Output
//Child class (1st)
//Parent Class (second)
```

But If you want to Access the `init()` method of Parent class before the subClass(es), you have to write `super.init()` inside the `init()` method of child class(es)

```js
class anotherClass {
 override init(){
    super.init()     //Accessing the Parent class constructor
    print("Child Class")
  }
}
```

Output will be:

```js
var sub=anotherClass()
//Output
//Parent Class (1st)
//Child class  (second)
```